# how to transfer data from array to function

Tags: c#

i need to transfer data from array to function in C#

the function:

```
    public void  InsertData(params  string [] DATA)
    {
        string MAC, ID_OLD, ID_NEW, Serial;
        MAC    = DATA[0].ToString();
        ID_OLD = DATA[1].ToString();
        ID_NEW = DATA[2].ToString();
        Serial = DATA[3].ToString();
    }
```

in the main:

```
string[] arr;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      arr = new string[5];

      arr[0] = "1";
      arr[1] = "2";
      arr[2] = "3";
      arr[3] = "4";

      InsertData(arr);
}
```

but its not working

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: you can remove "params" keyword from insertdata

Comment: Your InsertData method isn't doing anything useful, it just assign values to variables... what do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 2):

The `params` modifier is used not to pass an array, but for the caller to be able to pass any number of arguments.

Therefore, in this case, when you're trying to pass an actual array, you don't need the `params` modifier.

Just use `public void InsertData(string[] data)` instead.